# Express.js использовать html вместо pug(jade)

Tags: node.js, express, pug

только начал изучать node.js по заграничным гайдам и там используют pug, а мне это не особо нравится, т.к. уже имеется готовая верстка(html) с которой хочется продолжать работать. Погуглив, нашел возможность писать html поставив лишь точку после html

```
doctype html
html.<<<точка
```

Но существует ли возможность использоваться именно документ с разрешением html вместо pug, если да, то что нужно поменять в app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
var http = require('http');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Порт 3000");
});
```

Comment: Так используйте `sendFile` вместо `render`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного контекста для тех кто заинтересуется этим вопросом.

Фрэймворк ExpressJS предполагает использование компонентов middleware для обработки запросов. Для приема файлов, организации cookie, и даже использования шаблонизаторов типа pug.

Если хочется чтобы веб-приложение по определенному адресу возвращало готовый *статический* файл, то нужно сделать две вещи:

1. Создать папку из который вы запускаете проект, например static. Положить в нее нужные файлы
2. Сконфигурировать middleware фреймворка, чтобы он знал где искать *статические* файлы

Строчка кода будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Более подробную документацию по этому вопросу можно найти на официальном [сайте](https://expressjs.com/ru/starter/static-files.html).